# PostgreSQL+PostGIS creating GeoJSON with ST_MakeLine

Tags: postgresql, geojson, linestring, route, postgis-2.3

Trying to get a valid geojson response from my PostgreSQL(9.6.3) + PostGIS (2.3.2) to track routes. I have a table of GPS positions of the form:

```
CREATE TABLE public.gps
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('gps_id_seq'::regclass),
  device_id integer, -- Device ID of GPS Device
  timecol bigint, -- Timestamp we use for linking video and GPS
  distance_from_hub double precision, -- Distance from nearest hub
  distance_from_hub_id integer, -- ID of nearest hub
  itudes_3d geography(PointM,4326)
)
```

I am trying to get a valid GeoJSON with the route as a LineString. The coordinates of each point are stored in the itudes_3d. I am querying with:

```
select jsonb_build_object(
        'type', 'FeatureCollection',
        'features', jsonb_agg(feature)) AS route
        FROM ( select jsonb_build_object(
            'type','Feature',
            'properties',jsonb_build_object(
              'opa', 1,
              'fillopa', 0.5,
              'type', 0,
              'weight', 1,
              'start_time', :start_time:,
              'end_time', :end_time:,
              'colour', 
              '#333'),
            'geometry', geometry.geoline::json) 
            FROM (select ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_MakeLine(geom.itudes_3d))::jsonb as geoline 
              FROM (select itudes_3d::geometry, ST_M(itudes_3d::geometry) as gtime
                FROM gps 
                WHERE device_id=:device_id: AND 
                timecol > :start_time: AND 
                timecol < :end_time: 
                ORDER BY timecol ASC) 
              AS geom) 
            AS geometry)
         AS feature
```

where :start_time:,:end_time: and ":device_id:" are placeholders for this explanation.

What I get back is:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"jsonb_build_object": {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[174.821949, -35.829088], [174.820518, -35.82855], [174.818997, -35.827884], [174.818997, -35.827884], [174.818696, -35.827857], [174.818363, -35.827694], [174.816604, -35.826887], [174.816275, -35.826737], [174.815868, -35.826569], [174.815188, -35.826255], etc...
```

The problem I have is the {"jsonb_build_object": label in the features... really I want:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[174.821949, -35.829088], [174.820518, -35.82855], [174.818997, -35.827884], [174.818997, -35.827884], [174.818696, -35.827857], [174.818363, -35.827694], [174.816604, -35.826887], [174.816275, -35.826737], [174.815868, -35.826569], [174.815188, -35.826255], etc...
```

Can anyone identify where I have gone wrong in constructing this?

To me it looks like the subquery is being named in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
'features', jsonb_agg(feature)) AS route
```

to

```
'features', jsonb_agg(feature.jsonb_build_object)) AS route
```